# Multi Wi-Fi Router Network Assigning IP Addresses Outside Subnet

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, dhcp, wifi-configuration, subnet

As illustrated [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/17SHwlZIcL0dnqRT9dSBXZ7Z2IYbiYK5w/view?usp=sharing), I have a home network with two 5G wifi routers. ROUTER A (the ARRIS Surfboard) is also the modem that has DHCP enabled and is the default gateway. ROUTER B (A NETGEAR R6700) has DHCP disabled and has an IP set to 192.168.1.2 on the local network. ROUTER A's DHCP range is set to 192.168.1.5 through 192.168.1.254. ROUTER B and ROUTER A are physically connected via ethernet cable to each other's LAN port.

The problem I am having is when a client connects to ROUTER B, it is assigned an IP of 169.254.X.X and has no internet connectivity. Any clients connecting to ROUTER A function as normal.

I want clients connecting to ROUTER B to be assigned an IP from ROUTER A's DHCP server on the same subnet as clients connecting to ROUTER A.

Comment: Between what subnets is Router B routing? And why do you want clients on router B’s subnet to have IP addresses assigned to a different subnet (addresses from A’s DHCP pool) than the one they’re on (B)? This does not make sense, or I might have misunderstood. Could you draw a simple diagram showing the subnets and how they’re connected?

Comment: I'm trying to have all clients on the same subnet, despite having more than one wifi router. So regardless of which wifi router a client connects to, I want them to be on the same subnet of 255.255.255.0.  The additional router is essentially extending the range of the main router I have on a different level of the house. The link posted in the question shows a diagram of what I'm trying to achieve.

Comment: So you don't use the second router as a router, only as a switch. Do the clients connect to Wifi or directly to one of the ethernet ports? I'm not too familiar with the Netgear R6700, but does it have an option for "Wireless isolation" or something like it? Are your clients on an isolated Guest network maybe?

Comment: hi, see if it's helpful to you: https://superuser.com/questions/627609/how-can-i-put-two-wireless-routers-on-the-same-subnet